# How would I get a list of column name & data type for each column in a table in .NET?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, vb.net

Suppose I have a table called TABLE1 in SQL Server 2008 R2. From this table I would like to  programmatically get a list of columns and their data types in C# or VB.NET. Essentially something like executing "sp_help TABLE1". Any tips?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT c.*
FROM information_schema.columns c
WHERE c.table_schema = 'dbo'    --or whatever
AND c.table_name = 'yourTable'
ORDER BY c.ORDINAL_POSITION
```

Answer (score 5):

The information schema views unfortunately miss a lot of important information. Take a look at this link.

- [The case against INFORMATION_SCHEMA views](https://sqlblog.org/2011/11/03/the-case-against-information_schema-views)

You will get more detailed information querying the sys catalogs instead.

Comment: My first thought when I saw this was "Yeah, but INFORMATION_SCHEMA.* is ANSI compliant". Aaron's take on the debate is very interesting.  And he clearly addressed my "Yeah, but..." argument.  Thanks for the link!

Comment: And is ANSI compliance really that big of a deal? I mean in reality we don't just go changing the DBMS all the time. I like to use the tools available for the system I am using. If that means I can squeak a small amount of performance or usability by not being 100% compliance then so be it.

Comment: No, it's not that big of a deal.  As a dba, I've been working with SQL Server almost exclusively for a long time.  And I'm not looking for a career change to another RDBMS vendor.  :)  It might be more important to developers, though.  Sometimes they have to support multiple RDBMS's...

Answer (score 4):

Try this query.

```
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'Table1'
```

Comment: DMason beat you to it. Thank you!