# How to get table columns values from SQL Server database

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

```
var reader = new SqlCommand("Select * from sys.columns", MyCon).ExecuteReader();
```

This shows this [strange output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dYcdA.png)

What I want is to get the columns values (nvarchar, varchar and so on...) from the database table as a string.

This query is not working in SQL Server I tried it

```
Show Columns From MyTable
```

it shows

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'From'.'

Comment: 'This query is not working in Sql Server', what do you mean?

Comment: can you share the expected output

Comment: [EXEC sp_help 'dbo.mytable';](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/view-the-table-definition)?

Comment: I mean I learned it from Sololearn

Comment: Google 'How to get SQL Server column *types*'.

Comment: I found what I want here
[a list of column data type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25509140/how-would-i-get-a-list-of-column-name-data-type-for-each-column-in-a-table-in)

Comment: `Show Columns From MyTable` is quite obviously not a valid query. The output you are showing is the result of a single row of `sys.columns`, the documentation is [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-columns-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15), you are also missing a join to `sys.types` and `sys.tables` so you cannot see the *name* of a column data type, only its type ID (`127` is `bigint`). Also `var reader` should be in a `using`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start checking this query:

```
SELECT *
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
```

You can access the data that you want to in this view.

Table name, column name, data type... It's all there.

This is the doc from MS, about the information_schema views:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-information-schema-views/columns-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: Thank you, but how to get all Table columns Datatype by it, Sorry I new to sql

Comment: another(and more convenience) way is via [DbConnection.GetSchema](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/getschema-and-schema-collections)

Comment: `information_schema` is for compatibility only, OP should use `sys.columns`